# How to get save a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt

How to get save popup from javascript function,
I am passing the file path from xsl to javascript, it is getting passed also, but I am unable to save that file to disk,
I tried

1. `window.open(path)` --> File is getting opened in new window successfully.
2. `document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, path)` --> HTML content of the page from where I am  saving is getting saved in the file. (Not the content of actual file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work, I'm not sure:

```
var popup = window.open(path);
popup.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, path);
```

In your code you're saving the current document, not the document in the popup.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thanks for you response. I am able to save the file. but before saving it is getting opened in a new window. I actually don't want to open that file. I have to simply save that file to disk.

Comment: The usual way this is handled is on the server -- open a URL that sends the file as an attachment.